# tsql - distributing multiple event durations over time interval islands

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, intervals

In sql server 2012 I need to distribute a number of event durations over a number of (island) time intervals.

The scenario is a manufacturing environment where a number of 'productive periods' are defined throughout the duration of a shift.  These are the islands and may not be contiguous.

During the shift, multiple durations of downtime can occur for different reasons and these are captured and stored as a duration only (with no reference to timestamps) with a foreign key relationship to the shift in which they occurred.

I need to be able to distribute the duration records across the productive time periods so as to Pack durations that are shorter than a period and split durations that are longer than a period.

Example data

Productive Periods 'Islands'

```
Idx  StartTime                 EndTime
1    2015-12-01 01:00:00.000   2015-12-01 02:00:00.000
3    2015-12-01 03:00:00.000   2015-12-01 04:00:00.000
6    2015-12-01 06:00:00.000   2015-12-01 08:00:00.000
8    2015-12-01 10:00:00.000   2015-12-01 11:00:00.000
10   2015-12-01 12:00:00.000   2015-12-01 14:00:00.000
12   2015-12-01 15:00:00.000   2015-12-01 16:00:00.000
```

Durations

```
Idx DurationMins
1   90
2   60
3   150
4   30
```

I need to distribute the Durations across the above periods so the result set looks like below (or similar).  The order doesn't really matter as the durations don't have a relationship to actual time. (only that they occurred sometime during the productive time islands).  It would even be acceptable to sort both the periods & durations by duration desc so as to possibly reduce the number of split events.  The reason I need to turn the durations into time intervals is that I need to display this data on a time axis chart report along with other time sensitive data and so need to give the duration events some start & end timestamps.

Desired result set:

```
Dur       Packed Period
Idx  Dur  Dur    Idx     StartTime                EndTime         
1    90    60     1      2015-12-01 01:00:00.000  2015-12-01 02:00:00.000
1    90    30     3      2015-12-01 03:00:00.000  2015-12-01 03:30:00.000
2    60    30     3      2015-12-01 03:30:00.000  2015-12-01 04:00:00.000
2    60    30     6      2015-12-01 06:00:00.000  2015-12-01 06:30:00.000
3    150   90     6      2015-12-01 06:30:00.000  2015-12-01 08:00:00.000
3    150   60     8      2015-12-01 10:00:00.000  2015-12-01 11:00:00.000
4    30    30     10     2015-12-01 12:00:00.000  2015-12-01 12:30:00.000
```

So, in the above example the 4 Duration records would be split into 7 Time interval records as per above.  I have tried a few different methods including recursive cte, self joins & cross applies but haven't been able to come up with a solution as yet.

It seems like an interval packing problem with the added complexity of distributing the time durations.

Any help or direction that anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, your requirements make no sense :) Second, I would use cursors (temp tables) - outer cycle over intervals records, inner  cycle (rather queue) over downtime records. On every start or end of interval or change of 'consumed' downtime record insert event into thrid temp table and return this third table records from procedure. (We have performed similar kind of calculation to fill multiple product lines from different batches - you just have time islands instead of product lines and duration values instead of quantities.)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Arvo, based on your hint I was able to get a solution working using nested while loops instead of cursors (as we are trying to avoid using them if possible and the number of records in each call to this function will be small).  It is understandable that my requirements don't make sense without understanding the bigger picture as to why I need to transform the data in such a way but I won't bore you with the details.
I will post my solution here in a couple of days (when I get through the complete implementation). Thanks.